# Having trouble parsing using sscanf

Tags: c, io, scanf

I am trying to parse a string format into `char*` using `sscanf`, but I'm having trouble doing so.

String format:

```
Track ID<>Song ID<>Artist Name<>Song Title
```

Example:

```
TRMMMYQ128F932D901<SEP>SOQMMHC12AB0180CB8<SEP>Faster Pussy Cat<SEP>Silent Night
```

All I want to do is get the artist name and song title. Here is how I implement `sscanf`.

```
  char* songName = " ";
  char* artistName = " ";
```

But none of these seem to return anything.

```
  sscanf(buffer, "%*s<>%*s<>%s<>%s", artistName, songName);
  sscanf(buffer, "%*[^'<>'],%*[^'<>'],%[^'<>'],%s", artistName, songName);
```

If anyone has any tips or advice, that would extremely helpful.

Comment: One problem is that `"%s"` stops reading *on white-space*.

Comment: Probably a good idea to read the manual page for `sscanf`

Comment: Look at `"%*[^'<>'],"`.  After scanning characters that are not `'<>'`, how can `','` be the next character?

Comment: You need to allocate modifiable space for `songName` and `artistName`; string literals cannot be modified safely.  They may make the program crash; they may cause confusion by sharing the same space; they definitely don't allocate enough space.  Use `char songName[64]; char artistName[64];` or something.

Comment: Why does the 'string format' list `<>` as the separator when the example seems to use `<SEP>` for the same job.  That's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and thanks for the pointers. I was using ',' as my separator instead of <'SEP> and I did not allocate space for songName and artistName.